# Apache Ignite 2.15 Startup Failure with JDK 17

Tags: ignite, java-17, apacheignite

I recently upgraded the `Apache Ignite` version to `2.17` and `JDK` version to `17`.But I am getting below exception in line of code `var ignite = Ignition.TryGetIgnite() ?? Ignition.Start(igniteConfiguration);` and also am specifically setting JVMOptions to `igniteConfiguration.JvmOptions.Add("-Xms1g -Xmx1g");` to overcome from `heap outofmemory exception`.

**Exception :**

```
Service cannot be started. Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: JNI_CreateJavaVM failed: InvalidArguments
   at IgniteService.IgniteServiceWrapper.Start()
   at IgniteService.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_9
   at Topshelf.ServiceConfiguratorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<WhenStarted>b__0(T service, HostControl control)
   at Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1.DelegateServiceHandle.Start(HostControl hostControl)
   at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsServiceHost.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

I tried setting other JVM Options and reinstalling JAVA_HOME which didn't solve the problem

Comment: There is no Ignite 2.17, can you please clarify the version used?

Comment: Sorry , Its Ignite 2.15 iam using

Answer (score 0):

Each JVM option should be specified separately.

Replace

```
JvmOptions.Add("-Xms1g -Xmx1g");
```

With

```
JvmOptions.Add("-Xms1g");
JvmOptions.Add("-Xmx1g");
```

Comment: Yes I replaced as you suggested and getting following exception.  Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Java exception occurred [class=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, message=Java heap space] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformConfigurationUtils.readIgniteConfiguration(PlatformConfigurationUtils.java:773)
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.dotnet.PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.processPrepareResult(PlatformDotNetConfigurationClosure.java:195)
 at

Comment: Do you have enough free memory on the machine? I can't reproduce the problem, the node starts even with default settings (`Ignition.Start()`).

Comment: Yes I have 19GB of memory in my machine

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer? Is there anything else in the configuration that might affect memory usage?

Comment: there is another advance configuration by default for Ignite is for JVM Initial Memory is 512 and JVM max memory is 1024

Comment: A reproducer is required to provide further assistance.

Comment: Hi, I created sample application from my codebase to reproduce this issue and share it with you. During this time, what i noticed is, Its working fine without any issue, but when caching is not happening, which is throwing an different error as below.[01:58:49,281][SEVERE][client-connector-#109][ClientListenerNioListener] Failed to parse client request.
org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException: Unsupported cache mode at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheConfigurationSerializer.read(ClientCacheConfigurationSerializer.java:454) at